# Getting a consistent read from a slave

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there is any way on a MySQL slave server to get a "consistent read" for a specific query. Let's say I send a query to the slave server at 8:30:15, and at that moment, the slave is still processing queries from the master bin log with timestamps dating from before that point in time. For that specific query though, I specified in some way to the slave that I want a consistent read, so the slave would put a hold on the read query until it has caught up to 8:30:15 in the master bin log, thus allowing me to receive a result that is consistent with what would have been given by the master had it received the query instead. Of course, that would cause a delay for me while I wait for my read result, which I wouldn't have to suffer if I had requested directly from the master, but it still allows me to send that query to the slave and get a consistent read from it.

Is there anything in MySQL that allows for this kind of query specific options on a slave?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Ask a DBA.

Comment: @tadman That's what I figured :( Thought it was worth asking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Slave can't server the query with the latest update so we can as below.

In this kind of scenario we should mark the HttpSesion as dirty, so that all the reads will go to the master instead of slaves which will server the latest copy.

Comment: I am already using a solution similar to this, but I thought it would be nice to be able to specify for specific queries that we want consistent read without having a whole session being directed to the master when only 1 or 2 queries might need that consistency.

Comment: @Jerome  Ok. Then you can  redirect these queries to contact master instead of slave from application as well.